# Update Query using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to update a column(flag) in a table with name **Employee**. 
basing on value(deptid from other table from **Department** table)

The deptid is in many-to-one relationship with Employee table.

```
 <many-to-one name="deptId"     class="Department"      column="deptId"  update="true"/>
```

I have written a HQL query for updating the flag value of the employee. I think i am making a mistake in the below code.

```
 public void updateEmployeeTable(Employee emp){
      String query = "update  " + Employee.class.getName()  + " set flag=? "
                + " where deptid = ? ";

        Object[] values = new Object[]{"flag value from form", "emp.getDeptId()"};
        getHibernateTemplate().update(emp);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass objects like this:

```
Object[] values = new Object[]{flag, emp.getDeptId()};
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(query, values);
```